# No data when WCF return ArrayList?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, arraylist

I do *not* receive any exceptions from the following code, but I also don't receive any data, why is this?

My DataAccess,

```
public ArrayList get_devices(string CityName, string Date1)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    ArrayList m = new ArrayList();
    DataSet1TableAdapters.Tb_CityTableAdapter City = new DataSet1TableAdapters.Tb_CityTableAdapter();
    value = City.Select_CityId(CityName);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  TB_Destiniation.Dest_Time, TB_Bases.Bases_Num, TB_Company.Company_Name    FROM            TB_Destiniation INNER JOIN TB_Bases ON TB_Destiniation.Bases_Id = TB_Bases.Bases_Id INNER JOIN  TB_Company ON TB_Bases.Company_Id = TB_Company.Company_Id WHERE  City_Id='" + value + "' AND Dest_Date='" + Date1 + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int x = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string[] record = new string[2];
        //String Re = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
        record[0] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
        record[1] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2));

        m.Add(record);
        x++;
    }
    return m;
}
```

This is my OperationContract,

```
[OperationContract]

[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = 

WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Get?CityName={CityName}&Date1={Date1}")]

ArrayList get_devices(string CityName, string Date1);
```

These are my IService1 Members,

```
#region IService1 Members

public ArrayList get_devices(string CityName, string Date1)
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    return dataAccess.get_devices(CityName, Date1);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: There is no error in my code but i get No data received

Comment: Ensure has value in databse ;)

Comment: i checked the value of arraylist "m" and i get the desire value form database

Comment: Hello can any one help me??????